QML TapHandler: how to ensure only top-most handler gets the events
As I understand it, if you have more than one QML TapHandler covering the same location, they all get the tap event by default; but you can change this behaviour using the grabPermissions property.
In my example, if I click/tap on overlay I want only its TapHandler to get the event. How do I do this?
Here's what I have tried:
Rectangle {
    id: area
    width: 300; height: 300
    color: "yellow"

    TapHandler {
        id: areaTapHandler
        grabPermissions: PointerHandler.ApprovesTakeOverByAnything | PointerHandler.ApprovesCancellation
        onTapped: console.log("Area tapped")
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: overlay
    x: 50; y: 50
    width: 200; height: 200
    color: "red"

    TapHandler {
        id: overlayTapHandler
        grabPermissions: PointerHandler.CanTakeOverFromAnything
        onTapped: console.log("Overlay tapped")
    }
}

and here's the output:
qml: Overlay tapped
qml: Area tapped

Before anyone asks why I'm not using MouseArea, this is a simplified example and I have many reasons within my real app... and besides that's not the point as I'm asking about TapHandler which is a documented QML component and I want to understand it better.

The default gesturePolicy for TapHandler is TapHandler.DragThreshold. From the documentation, this policy is a passive grab. If you want an exclusive grab, you need to use one of the other gesture policies like TapHandler.WithinBounds.

Brilliant! Simple and elegant. I've removed my custom grabPermissions as they are unnecessary when using gesturePolicy: TapHandler.WithinBounds on overlayTapHandler.

You can suppress other lower level TapHandler if higher TapHandler are pressed, e.g.
    Rectangle {
        width: 300; height: 300; color: "yellow"
        TapHandler {
            enabled: !overlayTapHandler.pressed
            onTapped: console.log("Area tapped")
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: 50; y: 50; width: 200; height: 200; color: "red"
        TapHandler {
            id: overlayTapHandler
            onTapped: console.log("Overlay tapped")
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
Alternatively, you can let all TapHandler.onTapped events fire normally, but only react to the first in the sequence. We can make use of Qt.callLater() as a means to filter and react to only the first event in a sequence:
    Rectangle {
        width: 300; height: 300; color: "yellow"
        TapHandler { onTapped: notify("Area tapped") }
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: 50; y: 50; width: 200; height: 200; color: "red"
        TapHandler { onTapped: notify("Overlay tapped") }
    }
    property bool notifying: false
    function notify(str) {
         if (notifying) return;
         notifying = true;
         Qt.callLater(() => {
             console.log(str);
             notifying = false;
         });
    }

You can Try it Online!
